# How is it possible to plot a set of subplots in a loop and save each time the subplots in an outer loop?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot the results of two inner loops in a single subplot after each iteration without closing it and this would be place in an outer loop and after each iteration of outer loop, I'd to save the plots. But unfortunately it just plots the last set of data in each loop. How could I manage to plot them all?

```
     shape=['.','s','^']
     colors=['r','b','m','c']    
     for l in range(len(rg)):
        for ii in range(len(ANISO_POLY)):
            for iii in range(len(ST_INT)):
                rc('text', usetex=True)
                rc('font', family='serif')
                fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,7.5))
                ax = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
                ax.set_xscale('log')
                #m, mean_D1, stdev_D1, mean_D2 and stdev_D2 are generated in the inner loop each time
                ax.errorbar(m, mean_D1, yerr=stdev_D1, color=colors[ii], ecolor=colors[ii], fmt=shape[iii], capsize=0, elinewidth=1.0,linestyle='dashed' ,label=ANISO_POLY[ii]+','+ST_INT[iii])
                ax.set_xlabel(r'$\Theta$', fontsize=15)
                ax.set_ylabel(r'$D_1^{+}$', fontsize=15)
                fontsize=10
                for tick in ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
                    tick.label1.set_fontsize(fontsize)
                for tick in ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
                    tick.label1.set_fontsize(fontsize)            
                ax = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)
                ax.set_xscale('log')
                ax.errorbar(m, mean_D2, yerr=stdev_D2, color=colors[ii], ecolor=colors[ii], fmt=shape[iii], capsize=0, elinewidth=1.0,linestyle='dashed',label=ANISO_POLY[ii]+','+ST_INT[iii] )
                ax.set_xlabel(r'$\Theta$', fontsize=15)
                ax.set_ylabel(r'$D_2^{+}$', fontsize=15)
                fontsize=10
                for tick in ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
                    tick.label1.set_fontsize(fontsize)
                for tick in ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
                    tick.label1.set_fontsize(fontsize)
        lg=ax.legend(numpoints=1,loc="upper right", ncol=1,fontsize=8)
        lg.draw_frame(False)
        plotfile='A226_R.ellip'+rg[l]+'.pdf'
        plt.savefig(plotfile, dpi=50, bbox_inches='tight')
        plt.close()
```

It is my code, I don't know where I did mistake!!!??

Comment: Can you reduce this the the _minimum_ amount of code which will demonstrate your problem?  Many people (my self included) will not read that much irrelevant code to help you with your problem.  Replace all of your data with either random numbers or straight lines (`np.arange(10)`).

Comment: @tcaswell I tried to reduced useless parts of the code.

Comment: We don't need to see your axis label, we don't need your loops that generate the data, we don't need any of the legend code, ect.  From your text at the top if SO formats your code with a scroll bar on the right, you have too much code.  And your code is not indented correctly.

Comment: @tcaswell I hope it does work now according to your comments !

Comment: Getting better, don't need the axis labels or tick tweaking, but do need fake data ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the setup of each figure which I try to save stays in the outer loop, then the plot does not update each time.

```
colors = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, 12))
for l in range(len(rg)):
    color_count=0
    rc('text', usetex=True)
    rc('font', family='serif')
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,7.5))
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
    ax1.set_xscale('log')
    x0,x1 = ax1.get_xlim()
    y0,y1 =ax1.set_ylim(-2e-4,2e-4)
    ax1.set_yticks((-2e-4,-1.5e-4,-1e-4,-0.5e-4,0.0,0.5e-4,1e-4,1.5e-4,2e-4))
    ax1.set_yticklabels([r'$-2\times 10^{-4}$',r'$-1.5\times 10^{-4}$' ,r'$-1\times 10^{-4}$',r'$-0.5\times 10^{-4}$' , r'$0.0$', r'$0.5\times 10^{-4}$',r'$1\times 10^{-4}$',r'$1.5\times 10^{-4}$',r'$2\times 10^{-4}$'])
    ax1.set_xlabel(r'$\Theta$', fontsize=15)
    ax1.set_ylabel(r'$D_1^{+}$', fontsize=15)
    fontsize=10
    for tick in ax1.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
        tick.label1.set_fontsize(fontsize)
    for tick in ax1.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
        tick.label1.set_fontsize(fontsize)            
    ax1.set_aspect((x1-x0)/(y1-y0))
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2, aspect=1)
    ax2.set_xscale('log')
    ax2.set_ylim(-2e-4,4e-4)
    ax2.set_yticks((-2e-4,-1e-4,0.0,1e-4,2e-4,3e-4,4e-4))
    ax2.set_yticklabels([r'$-2\times 10^{-4}$',r'$-1\times 10^{-4}$' , r'$0.0$', r'$1\times 10^{-4}$',r'$2\times 10^{-4}$',r'$3\times 10^{-4}$',r'$4\times 10^{-4}$'])
    ax2.set_xlabel(r'$\Theta$', fontsize=15)
    ax2.set_ylabel(r'$D_2^{+}$', fontsize=15)
    fontsize=10
    for tick in ax2.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
        tick.label1.set_fontsize(fontsize)
    for tick in ax2.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
        tick.label1.set_fontsize(fontsize)
    for ii in range(len(ANISO_POLY)):
        for iii in range(len(ST_INT)):
            ax1.errorbar(m, mean_D1, yerr=stdev_D1, color=colors[color_count], ecolor=colors[color_count], fmt='.', capsize=0, elinewidth=1.0,linestyle='dashed' ,label='Poly. or.:'+ANISO_POLY[ii]+',St. int.:'+ST_INT[iii])
            ax2.errorbar(m, mean_D2, yerr=stdev_D2, color=colors[color_count], ecolor=colors[color_count], fmt='.', capsize=0, elinewidth=1.0,linestyle='dashed',label='Poly. or.:'+ANISO_POLY[ii]+', St. int.:'+ST_INT[iii])
            color_count+=1
    lg=ax2.legend(numpoints=1,loc=4, ncol=3,fontsize=5)
    lg.draw_frame(False)
    plotfile='A226_R.ellip'+rg[l]+'.pdf'
    plt.savefig(plotfile, dpi=50, bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.close()
```